# php undertsanding greedy vs. nongreedy matching

Tags: php, regex

This:

```
preg_match('~foo(.*?)(bar)?~','foo bar',$m);
```

gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => 
)
```

I'm kinda confused about this. I get that group 1 is giving me an empty string, because it's a lazy match. But shouldn't `(bar)?` be greedy and thus give me capture group 2?

Seems reasonable to me that what I *should* be getting is

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => 
    [2] => bar
)
```

where `[1]` is a space.  And yet.. this is not happening. Why?

Comment: **Off-topic:** Please change your name to `mysqli_noobie...`. Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi), and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @HamZa That made me chuckle!

Comment: If it worked the way you'd expect it to work, [0] would actually be "foo bar". [0] is the complete match.

Comment: See edit to my answer that answers your confusion. :)

Comment: @JohannesH. yar, i forgot i had wrapped "foo" when i was playing with it so i was confused. thanks!

Comment: @mysql_noobie_xxxx you might play at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) it's stylish and fast :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer here is surprisingly simple. The first group matches nothing (at first pass), not even the space. The second group tries to match the space with "bar", which, of course, fails. If there would be anything behind that that HAS to match, the engine would now backtrack and expand the first capturing group to match the space. But it's perfectly fine the way it is now (the second group actually CAN be emtpy), so it just stays that way.

To produce what you expect, try this:

```
preg_replace('~foo(.*?)(bar)?_~', 'foo bar_', $m);
```

---

In your edit, you added another capturing group. (.*) is now 2. It matches till the end of the string, as you thought it would. So you're right on that one, you just changed the example ^^

Comment: yeah I realized that right after I posted it, and then understood it wasn't the last one popping "bar", but the `(.*)`, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, this behaviour is correct.  From the [documentation on lazy matching](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php):

> if a quantifier is followed by a question mark, then it becomes lazy, and instead matches the **minimum number of times possible**

Since `(bar)?` is optional, `(.*?)` does not need to match anything in order for the regular expression to be successful.  Since the space between **foo** and **bar** was not captured, the expression cannot continue on and match **bar**.

Answer (score 2):

Entry '0' is always full matched pattern which in this case is **foo**.
First matching group however matches nothing as * used. Second group is optional.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Actually, if the first group wouldn't be lazy, the second one would capture the bar, even though it is still optional.

Comment: @JohannesH. huh.. `(foo)(.*)(bar)?` does indeed give me "bar" in `[2]`.. why is that?

Comment: That's because all capturing groups are greedy here. That means they match as much as they can. (foo) matches foo (in [1]), of course. (.*) matches the space - and the (bar) (in [2]). (bar)? matches nothing (so no [3])